# Trouble opening detailview from tableview

Tags: iphone, ios

Ok so I found this tutorial on xml parsing.
 http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/09/parsing-xml-in-an-iphone-app-tutorial/

Its pretty nice but the tweets he gets are cut off. So I think "thats cool I'll just open them  up in a detailView when the user clicks that table cell."  However while the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is firing. Nothing is happening.

Why? Because the navigation controller is null.  So more details.

This is a tab bar based application. 
On the first tab I have a button that leads to a tableview.

How do I add a UINavigation controller to this to make this work?

I have tried opening my first-tab xib and dragging in a navigation controller then changing its rootview to my tableview class. The table comes up but still the table cell click shows my navigation controller as null.

Comment: seems like your navigation controller is Null, can you try logging NSLog(@"%@",self.naviagationController) and check what is there?\

Comment: verify also that the name of nib is the good

Comment: OK so it its null. I have changed my above port a little to suit the problem.

Comment: @ rishi  Can you put your comment in as an answer so that I can accept it please?

Answer (score 1):

If the nib is named the same as the class (as you have it above) just do:

```
DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
```